# Remove or change the zero before table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, tocbibind

I wanted to add the *List Of Figures* (Lof) in my table of contents with this code inside my header:

```
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
  \tocchapter
  \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}
  \endgroup
}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{%
  \begingroup
  \tocchapter
  \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
  \endgroup
}
```

My main file looks like this :

```
\input{header}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother



\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\let\oldchapter\chapter

\renewcommand{\section}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}\oldsubsection}
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{chapter}\oldchapter}
\frontmatter


\include{kapitel/titelseite_Standard}

\include{kapitel/erklaerung}


\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\input{kapitel/Einleitung}


\input{kapitel/Grundlagen}
\input{kapitel/Programmierumgebungen}
\input{kapitel/Analyse}
\input{kapitel/Implementierung}
\input{kapitel/Test}
\input{kapitel/Fazit}
\input{kapitel/anhang}

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\bibliography{biblio/biblio}
```

[image]

Now my table of contents is treated as a chapter with a heading and before this heading is a zero. How can I change the zero to a one. My `documentclass` is `scrbook`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you, if you provide us with a (complete) minimum working example.

Comment: Is it really necessary to prepend `\section` etc. with `\counterwithin` -- each time when `\section` is called? By the way, the `tocbibind` package already adds the LoF and LoT to the ToC. Shall the LoF and LoT be numbered as chapters?

Comment: Yes without this  I would get false numbering inside sections and subsections under the figures and listings....

Comment: @skop: Please provide a compilable document, not the fragments from above

Comment: Remove `\tocchapter` from your `\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}`.

Comment: I just realized that `scrbook` is the class, so `tocbibind` in conjunction with `scrbook` is not recommended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\tocchapter` lets `\tableofcontents` use `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*` heading, so this will lead to `0 Contents`

However, it is a really **bad** idea to change `\tableofcontents` since `listings` hijacks `\tableofcontents` and will use basically the same code for `\listoflistings`.

In my point of view the redefinition of `\tableofcontents` should not be done at all, since `tocbibind` already adds LoF, ToC etc. to the ToC (if not prevented with `notoc` etc.

The `\counterwithin` statements before `\section` are not necessary, since `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}` is sufficient, since `subsection` is in the counter reset list of `section` and `chapter`, so a resetting of any of those counters will reset `lstlisting` as well.

`listings` defines the `lstlisting` counter only at `\AtBeginDocument` so `\counterwithin` can't be used before `\begin{document}` for this counter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocbibind}


% Actually not really needed!
% \AtBeginDocument{
%   \renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{%
%    \begingroup
%    \tocfile{\contentsname}{toc}
%    \endgroup
%  }
%}



%\input{header}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}
  \def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}{#1}{#2}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\frontmatter


%\include{kapitel/titelseite_Standard}

%\include{kapitel/erklaerung}


\tableofcontents


\mainmatter

\chapter[foo]{stuff}
\chapter{Foo stuff}

\section{Foo section}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection{Other foo subsection}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo again]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}

\section{Other foo section}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo again]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo again \thesection]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}


\chapter{Other foo chapter}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Foo again]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}



%\input{kapitel/Einleitung}


%\input{kapitel/Grundlagen}
%\input{kapitel/Programmierumgebungen}
%\input{kapitel/Analyse}
%\input{kapitel/Implementierung}
%\input{kapitel/Test}
%\input{kapitel/Fazit}
%\input{kapitel/anhang}

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\bibliography{biblio/biblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}` also changes the representation of the counter. There are better ways to remove the trailing zeros, though, than executing `\counterwithin` at each sectional command.

Comment: @egreg: I removed the `\counterwithin` statements already, my code is significantly different compared to the OP. As long as I don't know what the requested numbering format should be, I won't change to `\counterwithin*` etc.

Answer (score 4):

With the KOMA-Script class `scrbook` there is no need to load package `tocbibind`.

The TOC entries of the lists can be done by option `listof=totoc`. And if you really want an entry for the TOC in the TOC you can use `\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}`.

To ensure that `\lstlistoflistings` respects settings of KOMA-Script option `listof` load package `scrhack`.

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=4em
]{tocline}{lstlisting}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin{lstlisting}{subsection}%
  \xpatchcmd{\fnum@lstlisting}{\thelstlisting}{\thelstlisting\autodot}{}{\PatchFailed}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter[foo]{stuff}
\chapter{Foo stuff}
\section{Foo section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Listing}]
Boo
\end{lstlisting}
\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really want the special numbering of the listings you could use

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc
]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=4em
]{tocline}{lstlisting}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \counterwithin*{lstlisting}{subsection}%
  \renewcommand\thelstlisting{%
    \ifnum\value{section}=0
      \thechapter
    \else
      \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
        \thesection
      \else
        \thesubsection
      \fi
    \fi
    .\arabic{lstlisting}%
  }%
  \xpatchcmd{\fnum@lstlisting}{\thelstlisting}{\thelstlisting\autodot}{}{\PatchFailed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter[foo]{stuff}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Listing in Chapter 1}]
  Boo
\end{lstlisting}
\chapter{Foo stuff}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Listing in Chapter 2}]
  Boo
\end{lstlisting}
\section{Foo section}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Listing in Section 2.1}]
  Boo
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A Listing in Subsection 2.1.1}]
  Boo
\end{lstlisting}
\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]